# Localhost connection reset by peer, docker container(ubuntu) running angularjs webpack app

Tags: ubuntu, docker, networking

I am running my webapp within a ubuntu container, with the following dockerfile:

```
# docker.webpack test enviroment

FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /
COPY . /

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install fish -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && apt-get install nodejs -y
RUN npm install webpack -g
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
#RUN npm run webpack-dev-server prøver med cmd i stedet
CMD npm run webpack-dev-server
```

I start the app app with `docker run -p 1384:1483 epdspa` which returns:

```
> epd-portal-spa@1.0.0 webpack-dev-server /
> webpack-dev-server --open --inline

Project is running at http://localhost:1384/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from ./public/
Hash: 80935d7e0983c2034300
Version: webpack 3.8.1
Time: 9870ms
```

But when i run `curl localhost:1384` i get:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I also run the following commands from a terminal window on my local machine:

```
netstat -pnlt | grep :1384


tcp6       0      0 :::1384                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Why there is only a `Ipv6` version I'm not sure,

```
route 
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

More info about the docker network configuration:

```
'[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "d7c753e63270be9aae2af38ab1044966c066ad6e69fec0f95e28c7e3c850ff23",
        "Created": "2017-12-01T08:08:51.677254348+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "21bcc48764a7245a5f8ef851e3e16774e91d0447fac6fc614089b5b917b71b31": {
                "Name": "angry_bassi",
                "EndpointID": "c744a2a7f2596d743ed91756f846d455967bb634292190c69789b447cca5ca2d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I'm pretty sure there are some [OPTIONS], [COMMAND] or [ARG..] in the docker CLI that will work, but I can't seem to figure it out from the documenation.

Comment: Tangentially, you want to minimize the number of `RUN` statements.

Comment: Yes I agree, but this is more proof of concept than anything else

Comment: I think your issue is that your app is running on localhost (or 127.0.0.1) in your Docker container.  Only services running within the same Docker container will be able to connect to your app (even if you publish the port to host machine).  Try changing the app's host to something like `0.0.0.0`, which binds to all interfaces and then see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by changing the image from ubuntu to nginx with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM kyma/docker-nginx
RUN apt-get update

# Add src.
COPY public/ /var/www

CMD 'nginx'
```

running: `docker run -p 1384:80 -d epdspa` works fine